# How to override a collection with another collection in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I have a few instances of running app. Each instance is having its own DB, and some collections are content-based (they are the same in all instances - same name and same content).

When we update content-based collection, it will be updated only in one DB. Now, I want to apply those changes on other instances.

Do I have to drop that collection on other instances and copy the updated collection? Can I just override the whole collection with updated one? Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Have you tried this - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-copy-a-collection-from-one-database-to-another-in-mongodb ?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/#mongorestore) and [--drop](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/#std-option-mongorestore.--drop) option.

This is the flow:

1. Use [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/#mongodump) to export collections from updated database.
2. Use [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/#mongorestore) with [--drop](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/#std-option-mongorestore.--drop) option to override existing collection of other databases with collections from updated database. Before restoring the collections from the dumped backup, this will drop the collections from the target database. [--drop](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/#std-option-mongorestore.--drop) does not drop collections that are not in the backup.